# JMeter - Header manager alters the headers during test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have extracted the jwt token from the **User login controller** through my http service my test plan looks like this:

[image: Result tree]
[image: Test plan]

As seen in the images in login request it takes the header of **Breakdown Configuration** and it doesn't take authorization token value pass as a JSON object in `Bearer ${token`} although I have extracted it in JSON extractor and debug sampler shows it. I have also used the once only controller but it doesn't solve the issue.

Please help in the nested Header Manager and how to use it correctly. Even I have used **Bean Shell processor** under my GETALL Bd-config  request and pass the command:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("BEARER")));
```

But it doesn't solve the issue. Please guide.

Comment: import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("token")));

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this `Extract token` [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) at the same level as other [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - you will need to remove the Debug Sampler and use i.e. [Debug Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) instead as given your current Test Plan:

1. `Extract token` Post-Processor is being applied to `Login` sampler and (hopefully) gets the token
2. `Extract token` Post-Processor is being applied to `Debug Sampler`, at this time your `${token}` variable **gets overwritten** with the blank or default value. One more error is that you're defining the variable holding the token as `token` and referring `BEARER` which doesn't have any value
3. Your GetAll Bd-config` sampler uses default or blank value

Check out [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) article for more information regarding JMeter test elements scope and properly placing them to achieve your goals.

Suggested test plan configuration would be something like:

[image]